# "No such file or directory exist", but it obviously does

Tags: python, pandas, import-from-excel

I'm trying to import multiple excel files to a DataFrame but I get the error: FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'test1.xlsx'

The code:

```
path=os.getcwd()
files = os.listdir(path+"/testimport")

df = pd.DataFrame()

for f in files:
    data = pd.read_excel(f,
                           sheet_name = "Data",
                           skiprows = range(0, 4),
                           usecols = "B:I,P:V")
    df = df.append(data)
```

However, when I try to print the files it actually do work:

```
in:    for f in files:
        print(f)
        
out:    test1.xlsx
        test2.xlsx
```

How is this possible and how to solve it? I've tried absolute path but same result.

Comment: Provide `read_excel` with the **full path**.  `listdir` only returns the filename.

Comment: Perhaps `pd.read_excel(path + "/testimport/" + f, ` instead since it looks like `f` merely contains the filename, not its full path.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alternatively to the posted answers, you can actually simplify your code by using [scandir](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.scandir) instead of [listdir](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.listdir), which yields [DirEntry](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.DirEntry) objects, which have the full path available as a `path` attribute

```py
import os

df = pd.DataFrame()

for f in os.scandir(os.path.join(os.getcwd(), "testimport")):
    data = pd.read_excel(
        f.path,
        sheet_name="Data",
        skiprows=range(0, 4),
        usecols = "B:I,P:V"
    )
    df = df.append(data)
```

Answer (score 2):

You should provide the full path (including the directory names) for the input files. Currently, you are only providing the file names. So, the read line should be something like below:

```py
data = pd.read_excel(os.path.join(path, "testimport", f), sheet_name = "Data", skiprows = range(0, 4), usecols = "B:I,P:V")
```

Note: `os.path.join` is the safer way to concatenate directory/file names, otherwise your code would be error prone in the case of extra forward slashes or when running in different operating systems.

Answer (score 1):

You can also changes the current working directory **os.chdir('./testimport')**:

```
os.chdir('./testimport')
path=os.getcwd()
 
files = os.listdir(path)
 
df = pd.DataFrame()
 
for f in files:
    data = pd.read_excel(f,
                           sheet_name = "Data",
                           skiprows = range(0, 4),
                           usecols = "B:I,P:V")
    df = df.append(data)
```